# SQL Server : prevent change of field value when it was once != NULL

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a trigger in SQL Server that prevents an update on a row if one specific field in that row already contains NON-NULL values.

It should then just ROLLBACK the update.

Background: if a `onceChangedDate` is set, it shall not be able to change it or NULL it again.

Table structure:

```
ID, UserName, Hidden, ChangedOneDate
```

Each entry will have normally at creation:

```
ID, SomeUser, 0, NULL
```

I have a trigger which will set `ChangedOnceDate` to the current date as soon the "Hidden" is set to 1.

And then I want to prevent any change on `ChangedOnceDate` for future.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Some sample data, and details of expected behaviour for different DML statements will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to provide more details in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some what of a stab in the dark, but seems like an `EXISTS` where the value of the column in the `deleted` pseudo-table isn't `NULL` but is in the `inserted` pseudo-table is what you are after:

```sql
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SomeColumn varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                            NullableDate date NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY (ID));
GO
--Trigger solution
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_NullableDateNulled_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable 
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted i
                    JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
               WHERE d.NullableDate IS NOT NULL
                 AND i.NullableDate IS NULL)
        --Use an Error number relevant for your environment
        THROW 78921,
              N'A row where the column ''NullableDate'' has been set to NULL has been detected in the trigger ''trg_NullableDateNulled_YourTable''. Cannot update column ''NullableDate'' to be NULL when it previously had a non-NULL value in the object ''dbo.YourTable''.',
              16;

END;
GO
```

You can then test (and clean up) with the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeColumn, NullableDate)
VALUES('asda',NULL),
      ('wera',GETDATE());
GO
--Following fails
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NullableDate = NULL
WHERE SomeColumn = 'wera';
GO
--Following works
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NullableDate = GETDATE()
WHERE SomeColumn = 'asda';
GO
--Following works
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NullableDate = '20220317'
WHERE SomeColumn = 'wera';
GO
--Following fails (as now not NULL
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NullableDate = NULL
WHERE SomeColumn = 'asda';
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f7f32cebbd7b56f2639f4eb1cc1f7dd)

Comment: Thank you very much! With omitting "AND i.NullableDate IS NULL" this is exaclty what I was searching for! Maybe you could delete that part in the code then I can mark it as accepted. With keeping it, it would only trigger if I would reset it to NULL, but I want it to trigger everytime when it once was != NULL

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers the question, @karlo922 , then please do accept the answer as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the part below from @Larnu 's answer,

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i
                    JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
               WHERE d.NullableDate IS NOT NULL
                 AND i.NullableDate IS NULL)
```

to below

```sql
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted d WHERE d.NullableDate IS NOT NULL)
```

to get the exact behavior you want.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63c6d8d383fb9ece3b382476ae41cee6)

Comment: No this id not the behaviour I want. The behaviour I want is @Larnu 's answer without  "AND i.NullableDate IS NULL". With your solution I would disallow any change in the "updated" entry. But I only want to disallow a change from Not-Null to Null.